# Trouble removing "/" from a file using fart cli?

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-word, cmd.exe

**I have** one text file named `PASS.TXT` with content like this

- > `8PxNA0QuFVZozwA</p>`

**I need** to make the output file only contain this value

- > `8pxNA0QuFVZozwA`

  <sup>**Also note that the `p` here is in a small letter.**</sup>

---

### My Work

So here's the logic I've worked out with the [`fart.exe` cmd utility](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/)  to transform the file content accordingly per the above requirements and such

```
C:\fart.exe pass.txt "<" --remove pass.txt Replaced 1 occurrence(s) in
1 file(s).

C:\fart.exe pass.txt "/" --remove pass.txt Found 1 file(s).

C:\fart.exe pass.txt "p" --remove pass.txt Replaced 1 occurence(s) in
1 file(s).

C:\fart.exe pass.txt ">" --remove pass.txt Replaced 1 occurence(s) in
1 file(s).
```

**The problem** appears to be with this tool replacing the `"/"` character from the file for the `</p>` characters I need to remove entirely from the file content.

**Question:** Does anyone know how I may be able to easily solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the forward slash (**`/`**) character with the backslash (**`\`**) character while using `-C` parameter to tell it to use extended characters and it should work just fine.

```
fart "c:\folder\pass.txt" -C "\/" --remove
```

Additionally, since you state you need to remove the `</p>` characters entirely, you can just run it with the `"</p>"` characters passed as the first argument after the file name and it'll remove all those characters found in a group without the need to escape or use extended characters.

```
fart "c:\folder\pass.txt" "</p>" --remove
```

---

### Further Resources

- `FART /?`

  `-C, --c-style       Allow C-style extended characters (\xFF\0\t\n\r\\ etc.)`